# Confusion surrounding the definition of an outer measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, definition

I'm reading *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory* and I'm struggling to understand what the outer measure defined below would give as an "output."
As seen below, the outer measure $\mathbf{P}^*(A)$, for any subset $A \subseteq \Omega$, is defined to be the infimum of sums of $\mathbf{P}(A_i)$, where $\{A_i\}$ is any countable collection of elements of the original semialgebra $\mathcal J$ whose union contains $A$. What does the infimum of sums here mean? Is it be the smallest probability amongst all probabilities $\mathbf{P}(A_i)$ or what specifically? We know that for $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{4, 5, 6\}$, $\inf (A+B) = 5$. What would now be $\inf (\mathbf{P}(A)+\mathbf{P}(B)) = \cdots$ be? Sorry for the naive question and thanks in advance.

[image: Outer measure]

Comment: infimum in Latin for "greatest lower bound"

Comment: Thank you, but what would the greatest lower bound of sums of $\mathbf{P}(A_i)$ here be? $\sum_i \mathbf{P}(A_i)$ is a real number as I could imagine, what would its infimum or supremum then be? this is what I'm struggling with :(

Comment: You are looking at the infimum of a **set** of numbers, not an individual number, viz., the **set** of numbers of the form $\sum P(A_i)$ where $\{A_i\}$ satisfy your given conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much @AnginaSeng, I understood it now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The notation of the book is not so good. A cleaner notation is

$$
P^*(A):=\inf \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }P(A_k):A\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }A_k,\, \{A_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathcal{J}\right\}
$$